# /help/on-topic ссылается на английский /help/mcve

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

[/help/on-topic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ссылается на https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve вместо русского перевода: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готово, проверяйте.

Заодно исправил ряд знаков препинания и опечаток, кое-где уточнил формулировку. Переписал абзац про списки литературы, прежний был совершенно неактуален:

> - Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию. Для списков литературы выделены особые поддерживаемые сообществом вопросы. Вместо того, чтобы задавать новый вопрос, найдите уже существующий в [вопросе-указателе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/). Также список литературы и других ресурсов часто можно найти в описаниях меток по соответствующим темам.